# Why doesn't boost regex '.{2}' match '??'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex, trigraphs

I'm trying to match some chunks if interesting data within a data stream.

There should be a leading `<` then four alphanumeric characters, two characters of checksum (or `??` if no shecksum was specified) and a trailing `>`.

If the last two characters are alphanumeric, the following code works as expected. If they're `??` though it fails.

```
// Set up a pre-populated data buffer as an example
std::string haystack = "Fli<data??>bble";

// Set up the regex
static const boost::regex e("<\\w{4}.{2}>");
std::string::const_iterator start, end;
start = haystack.begin();
end = haystack.end();
boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;

// Try and find something of interest in the buffer
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
bool succeeded = regex_search(start, end, what, e, flags); // <-- returns false
```

I've not spotted anything in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax.html) which suggests this should be the case (all but NULL and newline should be match AIUI).

So what have I missed?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Mine (gcc) gives an explicit warning saying "trigraph ??> converted to }".

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013 with the 2008 tool chain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `??>` is a [trigraph](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative), it will be converted to `}`, Your code is equivalent to:

```
// Set up a pre-populated data buffer as an example
std::string haystack = "Fli<data}bble";

// Set up the regex
static const boost::regex e("<\\w{4}.{2}>");
std::string::const_iterator start, end;
start = haystack.begin();
end = haystack.end();
boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;

// Try and find something of interest in the buffer
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
bool succeeded = regex_search(start, end, what, e, flags); // <-- returns false
```

You can change to this:

```
std::string haystack = "Fli<data?" "?>bble";
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sbNk6qUAKNyCf82w) (note: I use `std::regex` which is more or less the same)

**NOTE:** trigraph is deprecated from C++11, will be (likely) removed from C++17

Comment: You got it. Very interesting - I'd not heard of trigraphs before!

Comment: They got removed (or deprecated?) in latest standards

Comment: @sehe deprecated from C++11, will be removed by C++17